# Spark Standalone + Zeppelin + Docker: how to set SPARK_HOME

Tags: docker, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I used [this](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/setup/deployment/spark_cluster_mode.html#spark-standalone-mode) script to build a Spark standalone cluster.

I want then to use Zeppelin from another container to submit jobs to that cluster.

The issue is when I try to run anything from zeppelin I get an exception:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: SPARK_HOME is not specified in interpreter-setting for non-local mode, if you specify it in zeppelin-env.sh, please move that into  interpreter setting`

How can I set the SPARK_HOME variable in Zeppelin container?

The issue is that Spark is in another container and I wonder if I am doing right thing at all?

Answer (score 0):

Build the image or use official zeppelin is same, so I just use official dockerhub image to explain the example:

```
$ docker run --rm  apache/zeppelin:0.8.1 cat /zeppelin/conf/zeppelin-env.sh.template | grep SPARK_HOME
## defining SPARK_HOME makes Zeppelin run spark interpreter process using spark-submit
# export SPARK_HOME                             # (required) When it is defined, load it instead of Zeppelin embedded Spark libraries
## without SPARK_HOME defined, Zeppelin still able to run spark interpreter process using embedded spark binaries.
## however, it is not encouraged when you can define SPARK_HOME
```

From above, you can see in this configure file, you can set `SPARK_HOME`, the only thing you need now is to write your own configure file something like next:

**zeppelin-env.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
export SPARK_HOME=xxxxxx
```

Then, mount it to container when you run like next to start the container, you may add other parameters according the document you referenced:

```
docker run -idt -v $(pwd)/zeppelin-env.sh:/zeppelin/conf/zeppelin-env.sh apache/zeppelin:0.8.1
```

Additional, I notice in your referred document also tell you do this, see [here](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/setup/deployment/spark_cluster_mode.html#4-configure-spark-interpreter-in-zeppelin)

Comment: I don't quite figure out where spark_home artifacts are mounted on zeppelin container...

Comment: In fact I never used zeppelin, but I think zeppelin just use spark-client to communicate with spark cluster, so install spark on host and mount it to zeppelin container for yourself is the way.

Answer (score 0):

In your docker-compose.yaml file, mount your local downloaded spark volume.
i.e.

```
zeppelin-notebook:
    image: apache/zeppelin:0.10.0
    ports:
      - "3000:8080"
    environment:
      - LOCAL_IP=zeppelin-notebook
      - SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark
    volumes:
      - ./zeppelin/notebooks:/zeppelin/notebook
      - <path to your local spark folder>/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop3.2/:/opt/spark
```

- execute `docker-compose up`.